# keyDown event is not working on textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I a have simple login form and I have set it's accept button property to "OK" button,
and I have a textbox "username" which I set it's KeyDown event to do some processing.
the Ok has enabled set to false.

```
btnOk.Enbled = false;  
this.AcceptButton = btnOk;
txtUsername.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(KeyDownHandle);
```

when I hit enter in the username  textbox I do some processing and then set accept button enabled to true.

```
private void KeyDownHandle(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // some processing
        btnOk.Enabled = true;
        txtPassword.Focus();
    }
}
```

then I write password in password textbox and hit enter so "OK.Click" is triggered.

but the problem is the keyDown is not working because "accept button".
what can I do to solve this?

Edit: Just want to say the problem is resolved if I set acceptButton to "none" but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you remove `this.AcceptButton = btnOk` from the constrctor (I suppose) and put it in the  `KeyDownHandler`, that way `btnOk` will accept Enter key only after it is enabled and after the username has been inserted. so the code should be like this:

```
btnOk.Enabled = false;
txtUsername.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);
btnOk.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);


private void KeyDownHandle(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // some processing
        btnOk.Enabled = true;
        this.AcceptButton = btnOk;
        txtPassword.Focus();
    }
}
```